# Android 11 (only) FragmentManager crashes - FragmentManager has been destroyed

Tags: android, kotlin, android-fragments, android-activity, android-11

Have there been any noticeable lifecycle changes on Android 11 that anyone has noticed?

My app works fine on pre-Android 11 OSes but on my Pixel 4 is crashing out everytime with the error:

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Fragment host has been destroyed
```

Is there anything under the hood that anyone else has noticed to just affect their app on Android 11?

I am using different files, for the activity and fragments.

I have a `TreasureHuntActivity` that Calls onCreate:

```
val fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.container, TreasureHuntMapFragment.newInstance(), "map-${index}").addToBackStack("map-${index}").commit()
fragmentManager.executePendingTransactions()
```

In the `TreasureHuntMapFragment` it calls

```
val intent = Intent(context, MainUnityActivity::class.java)
activity.startActivityForResult(intent, 33)
Handler().postDelayed({ activity.pushQuestionHintFragment() }, 1000)
```

Back in the `TreasureHuntActivity` it calls the `TreasureHuntQuestionHintFragment` to show

```
fun pushQuestionHintFragment() {
val fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.container, TreasureHuntQuestionHintFragment.newInstance(), "questionHintFragment-${specificQuestionId}").addToBackStack("questionHintFragment-${specificQuestionId}").commitAllowingStateLoss()
fragmentManager.executePendingTransactions()
}
```

This works on pre Android 11 where it works perfectly, as mentioned it doesn't work now on 11+. With further debugging it is showing `fragmentManager` as null, which was previously declared as
`var fragmentManager = supportFragmentManager`
globally in `TreasureHuntActivity`

If I debug on the Pixel 2 (earlier version of Android), the `fragmentManager` is not null and is `BackStackEntry`.

I have tried updating the decencies to be 2.2.0 or 2.3.0-alpha07 for lifecycle or fragment to be 1.3.0 and had no joy still.

The `fragmentManager` is only null on the Android 11 run when calling `pushQuestionHintFragment()`. If I debug, `this.isDestroyed` is true also, but only on Android 11.

Answer (score 0):

Use `supportFragmentManager` instead of `fragmentManager`

```
fun pushQuestionHintFragment() {
    val fragmentTransaction = supportFragmentManager.beginTransaction()
    fragmentTransaction.replace(
                R.id.container,
                TreasureHuntQuestionHintFragment.newInstance(),
                "questionHintFragment-${specificQuestionId}").addToBackStack("questionHintFragment-${specificQuestionId}")
                       .commitAllowingStateLoss()
    supportFragmentManager.executePendingTransactions()
 }
```